# Is there a way to rearrange the tabs in CKEditor dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I already have this code in CKEditor:

```
 CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    var dialog = dialogDefinition.dialog;


    if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {
        dialog.on('show', function () {
            this.selectPage('Upload');
    });

       dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'Link' );
       dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'advanced' );
       var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );

       infoTab.remove( 'txtAlt' );
       infoTab.remove( 'txtBorder' );
       infoTab.remove( 'txtHSpace' );
       infoTab.remove( 'txtVSpace' );
       infoTab.remove( 'cmbAlign' );

       var upTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'Upload' );
       var upButton = upTab.get( 'uploadButton' );
       var uploadBut = upTab.get( 'upload' );

       upButton.label = 'Upload Image';
       uploadBut.label = 'Upload Image';
    }
});
```

Which results to something like this when you click the upload image button on CKEditor:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJvpB.png)

This piece of code:

```
if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {
    dialog.on('show', function () {
        this.selectPage('Upload');
});
```

Sets the "upload" tab as the default. And it works well.

But what I really want to do is to place the "upload" tab right before the "image info" tab.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSSKs.png)

Is there anything in the CKEditor API that lets me do that? Or do I have to tinker with the dialog-plugin.js to be able to do that? And if it's the latter how do I do start to do that? I'm using the latest version of CKEditor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a work-around and I don't think this is a very good solution, but it works...

```
dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'Upload' );
dialogDefinition.addContents(upTab, 'info');
```

By putting these at the end of the codes, you remove the Upload tab and add it right away, but this time you place it right before the Info tab.

Comment: Its working fine, but it uncertainly stops the auto-ratio image width with height, and the image height and width is also not saved on **Image Info** tab.